# Cloth Simulation with Mesh Deform Modifier causes parts of mesh to stick?

Tags: cloth-simulation

I'm using a Mesh Deform Modifier to animate a complex belt model with a simpler mesh. I animated the location of the deform mesh so that the cloth simulation would have some movement to work with, but certain parts of my complex belt mesh are "sticking" in place and deforming the rest of the mesh. What is the reason for this?

Blend file: http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=49483

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason: It was because the mesh i used as the deform cage wasn't completely surrounding my complex mesh before i clicked bind. The vertices i left out were the ones that were sticking.